# How to include the comments xml in MrefBuilder (EXE)

Tags: c#, xml, sandcastle

I need to find the differences between two assemblies. The way I am doing this, is by using MRefBuilder generated xml files for both versions. I use C# to compare the xml files, and get only the methods, properties, and files that have changed. Then, i save the diff in XML file, and I generate a HTML report by using XSLT

I've got a new requirement; to add these extra comments

```
<summary>This method does this</summary>
<param name="prm1"></param>
```

in my HTML report. **While, these comments are included in the XML report generated by the VisaulStudio, I don't know how to add them to the report generated by the MRefBuilder.**

Is there a way--*other than code*--to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The short story: As I see your workflow it's a task of your (existing) C# code comparing the two xml files of the assemblies.

As I understand your workflow:

assemblies => MRefBuilder => two XML => your C# Code => one diff.xml => XSLT = HTML

But I'm a bit confused about your `... now I got the xml generated by visual studio which has these comments.`

I always have comments in my XML documentation files (!) depending on the inline code comments. So, if you want to generate a HTML report derived from a diff.xml by XSLT I think you need to do it by yourself.

I assume you have Visual Studio installed and Sandcastle Help File Builder integrated and you checked the XML documentation file option in the Build Output section.

[image]

BTW - my Sandcastle Help File Builder options inside Visual Studio are shown below:

[image]